# Creating an Array based on Condition of an enum

Tags: java, enums

I have an array which is tokenized

```
searchTerm = [flu , virus, AND, ebola]
```

i need the out put as

```
searchTerm = [flu virus, AND, ebola]
```

The enum condition can change

```
serarchTerm = ['flu', 'virus', OR, 'ebola']

public enum OperatorType
{ 
AND,
OR,
NOT,
IN,
ANY,
KEYWORD,
NONE
}
```

Help much appretiated.

What i have tried so far ...

```
String[] keywords = searchText.split(" ");
String[] keywordCondition = null;

    for(int index = 0; index < keywords.length; index++) {
        for(OperatorType opr : OperatorType.values()) {
            if(keywords[index] == opr.toString()) {
                // Some Logic here
                }                   
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is highly unclear. Can you please elaborate with more words  ?

Comment: I need to write a condition to match enums and create another array.

Comment: all array elements before enum should be treated as one element

Comment: what do you want as output on what ?

Comment: I have edited my post on what i have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do using [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/):

```
String keyRegex = " (AND|OR|NOT|IN|ANY|KEYWORD|NONE) ";
String[] input = { "flu", "virus", "AND", "ebola" };

String joined = String.join(" ", input); //added in 1.8, use StringBuilder in earlier versions
String replaced = joined.replaceAll(keyRegex, "\n$1\n");
String[] output = replaced.split("\n");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
// [flu virus, AND, ebola]
```

*However* if the original array was created by splitting the input from user, then this is extreamly backwards and use the original input directly instead of creating the `joined` variable.

Moreover, this will work properly if the keywords are inserted between regular text. You can create the `keyRegex` manually or by [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) from the enum names.

Comment: The method join(String, String[]) is undefined for the type String (error for the third line)

Comment: My bad, id was added in `1.8` version. Just join then old-fasion way with `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason for you to use `Enum`?

Because my guess judging by your problem statement that there isn't. So (also guessing) `searchText` is a `String` you split then you should not use `split` with `" "` but instead split your initial `String` with your desired delimiter as:

```
String[] keywords = searchText.split("AND");
```

and you will get the array you expect.

If on the other hand you need all delimiters simultaneously then use a regex inside `split` with multiple delimiters:

```
String[] keywords = searchText.split("(AND)|(OR)");
```

Comment: then my result  would be searchTerm = [flu virus, ebola] i need searchTerm = [flu virus, AND, ebola]

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
        String beforeEnum = "";
        for(int index = 0; index < keywords.length; index++) {*
            bool isEnum = false;
            for(OperatorType opr : OperatorType.values()) {
                if(keywords[index].equals(opr.toString())) {
                    isEnum = true;
                }                   
            }

            if(isEnum){
                if(!beforeEnum.equals("")){
                    newArray.add(beforeEnum);
                }
                newArray.add(keywords[index]);
            }
            else{
                beforeEnum = beforeEnum + " " + keywords[index];
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) to try to get your `String` value as an `Enum` member:

```
final String[] searchTerms = "flu virus AND ebola".split(" ");
final ArrayList<Object> terms = new ArrayList<Object>();
for (final String term : searchTerms) {
    try {
        terms.add(OperatorType.valueOf(term));
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { // This is not an operator
        if (terms.isEmpty() || !(terms.get(terms.size() - 1) instanceof String)) {
            terms.add(term);
        } else {
            terms.set(terms.size() - 1, terms.get(terms.size() - 1) + " " + term);
        }
    }
}

for (final Object term : terms) {
    System.out.println(term);
}
```

This will create an `ArrayList` containing `String` and `OperatorType` objects, that you can later identify using `instanceOf`.